# Delete a word without adding it to the kill-ring in Emacs

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

When switching files using the minibuffer (C-x C-f), I often use M-Backspace to delete words in the path. Emacs automatically places what I delete into the kill ring. This can be annoying, as sometime I am moving to another file to paste something, and I end up pasting part of the file path. I know there are workarounds, and the other code is still in the kill ring, etc, but I would just like to disable this functionality.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Emacs doesn't have a `backward-delete-word` function, but it's easy enough to define one:

```
(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (backward-word arg) (point))))
```

Then you can bind M-Backspace to `backward-delete-word` in `minibuffer-local-map`:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-map [M-backspace] 'backward-delete-word)
```

Comment: And here I've been going through life using only backspace and C-d to edit filenames in the mini-buffer.  :)

Answer (score 4):

See a discussion of this topic at `help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org`:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2011-10/msg00277.html

The discussion boils down to this short solution:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook'
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'kill-ring)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace the function called by `M-<backspace>`, namely `backward-kill-word`, with `backward-delete-word`, which you can easily define using the source definition of `backward-kill-word` found in lisp source for emacs. You do this by substituting `kill-region` for `delete-region`as in the following code, which also defines `delete-word` (delete word after the cursor). You can just paste this code in your .emacs file.

```
(defun delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters forward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-word arg) (point))))
(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-word (- arg)))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<backspace>") 'backward-delete-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<delete>") 'delete-word)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).