# How do I use backward-delete-word instead of backward-kill-word in emacs

Tags: emacs

I would prefer if the command backward-kill-word (C-backspace) would not append the word to the kill ring but simply delete it. Also for kill-word. (M-d), is there a delete-word equivalent?

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs minibuffer killring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133799/emacs-minibuffer-killring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133799) and in the emacswiki [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackwardDeleteWord). Hope that helps...